# How to enable or get the tracking URL in spark shell?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

When I give spark-shell or Spark-shell --master yarn, I don't find tracking Url on the console.

Say I have changed the no of executors and executor memory,I would like verify these Changes using tracking URL.

It will be helpful if I get to know how to get this tracking URL

Answer (score 4):

you can get the SparkUI URL programmatically :

```
val url = spark.sparkContext.uiWebUrl
```

Comment: Note this will only be valid so long as the Spark app is running.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using yarn,

1. Go to yarn applications in CM.
2. You will find your spark shell listed. Click your application
3. You will find a **Tracking URL**: ApplicationMaster this is the URL you are looking for.
   Let me know if this answers your query.

Comment: That app master will just redirect to the Spark UI, though